# Filter or search in jQuery easy Ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filtering, jquery-easyui

I have been working with a awesome plugin - **jQuery EasyUi** for displaying tree structure.
Everything is working fine except for search functionality, it does not give proper results.

```
Refer to http://jsfiddle.net/sanno_s88/rhqbk496
```

If I try to search for any parent nodes, it should also return the child nodes. But in this scenario, I used doFilter method it works properly with child nodes but trims the child nodes when we search for parent.

An example would be like to get all the child's as well when we search for any parent, as like we would get all child on search of javascript.

I can write my own search logic, but would wanted to know if we can do this using ***doFilter*** function.

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated!

Comment: doFilter search on child's and return it with it's parents, if you want this function to filter focus on parents only or both of it you should modified doFilter at jquery.easyui.min.js

Comment: Yup, I had to write custom function to achieve the desired functionality.
Also noticied that search on tree using jquery-easy-ui was very slow on mobile(performance was great on desktop), so had used another plugin called dynatree.
Thanks for your time to reply!

Comment: I am facing the same question. can you give me some advice about how to show children of the node which has been chosed ,thx in advanced